# CSS only on hover box with images

Tags: html, css

Can someone please explain how to create something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OlfU.png):

[image: Desired output]

To be more specific, when the user hovers the button, I am trying to make a box with images appear bellow the button.

The box stays there as long as the user keeps the mouse on the box or the button.

My code yet, working but without the images:

http://jsfiddle.net/6LUnV/1/

CSS

```
.tooltip{
    position: relative;
}

.tooltip:hover:after{
    background: #000000;
    top: 30px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    content: attr(id);
    left: -90px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 98;
    width: 200px;
}
```

HTML

`<button class="tooltip" id="Pick an image<img src='a.png'/><img src='b.png'/><img src='c.png'/><img src='d.png'/>" style="margin-left:160px;">Select</button>`

**EDIT: Question updated**

Comment: Although I understand, I think, what you are trying to do, your current implementation is odd. There is insufficient HTML and the CSS looks like it's been pasted from somewhere for something unrelated.

Comment: I am a beginner and I just took the CSS code from a tooltip tutorial. Can you please help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately, we're not able to provide tutorials for you. You might be lucky enough that someone will provide you with full code but that's a rarity. You should concentrate on getting the elements on the page first and then deciding how to hide and them reveal them. There are **many** ways to do this and we don't know what would be ideal for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What st. like that?

```
<style>

#select {position: relative; width: 80px; margin: 0 auto;}
button {width: 80px;}

#images {overflow: hidden; position: absolute; bottom: -50px; left: 50%; margin-left: -100px; width: 200px; display: none;}
img {float: left; width: 50px; height: 50px;}
img {background: red;}
img:nth-child(2) {background: green;}
img:nth-child(3) {background: blue;}
img:nth-child(4) {background: yellow;}

#select:hover #images {display: block;}

</style>

<div id="select">
    <button>select</button>

    <div id="images">
        <img>
        <img>
        <img>
        <img>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6LUnV/2/